# how to delete database of odoo in terminal from debian

Tags: odoo-9, debian-based

How can i delete the database of odoo 9 using terminal , but i have no idea how to do this . please share with me the process .

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/cache.py",          line 85, in lookup
value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 814, in check
, (model_name, uid,)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 141, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 220, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

This error will be found , when i open the odoo . so i think , if i delete the database there may be solve the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can manage databases (and delete them) via `/web/database/manager`.

On linux you can handle databases as described in [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-createdb.html):

```
# dropdb mydb
```